# Hibernate: 2 subclass mapping the same key column

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I would like to map the same key column, parent_id this example, across the subclasses. Both ClientProfileDO and BusinessProfileDO are inherited from UserProfileDO. They are on the same table, USERPROFILE. So, they refer the same foreign key on the Contact table. Is it logically incorrect?

```
<hibernate-mapping    package="com.rentorama2.frontpage.client.serialize"default-lazy="false">
<class name="UserProfileDO" table="USERPROFILE">
<id name="oid" type="long" column="oid" >
    <generator class="increment">
        <param name="initial_value">1</param>
    </generator>
</id>
<discriminator column="dcolumn" type="string" length="5"/>
<property name="acctOid">
    <column name="acctOid" />
</property>  
<property name="email">
    <column name="email"/>
</property>

<subclass name="ClientProfileDO" discriminator-value="CP">
    <list name="c_contacts" cascade="all">
        <key column="parent_id" not-null="true"/>
        <index column="idx"/>
        <one-to-many class="Contact"/>
    </list>
</subclass> 
<subclass name="BusinessProfileDO" discriminator-value="BP">
    <property name="b_updateAnnouncement">
        <column name="updateAnnouncement"/>
    </property>
    <list name="b_contacts" cascade="all">
        <key column="parent_id" not-null="true"/>
        <index column="idx"/>
        <one-to-many class="Contact"/>
    </list>
</subclass>
</class>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move the `Contact` one-to-many association into `UserProfileDO` base class:

```
<hibernate-mapping    package="com.rentorama2.frontpage.client.serialize"default-lazy="false">
    <class name="UserProfileDO" table="USERPROFILE">
    <id name="oid" type="long" column="oid" >
        <generator class="increment">
            <param name="initial_value">1</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="dcolumn" type="string" length="5"/>
    <property name="acctOid">
        <column name="acctOid" />
    </property>  
    <property name="email">
        <column name="email"/>
    </property>

    <list name="contacts" cascade="all">
        <key column="parent_id" not-null="true"/>
        <index column="idx"/>
        <one-to-many class="Contact"/>
    </list>

    <subclass name="ClientProfileDO" discriminator-value="CP">

    </subclass> 
    <subclass name="BusinessProfileDO" discriminator-value="BP">
        <property name="b_updateAnnouncement">
            <column name="updateAnnouncement"/>
        </property>
    </subclass>
</class>
```

And the `UserProfileDO` class will have a `Contact` list:

```
private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

public List<Contact> getContacts() {
    return contacts;
}

public void getContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But logically and for learning purpose, why is it a mistake?

Comment: If it's not a mistake, why not declare oid, acctoid, and email also in subclasses? And why even have UserProfileDO? Java Inheritance has both development and runtime benefits. If you don't want to use it, well, more power to you.

Comment: It's not a mistake. Moving the common properties to the base class is one advantage of using inheritance.